# How to whitelist an optional cookie using regex in skipper-filter of zalando

Tags: regex, cookies

I'd like to modify a Cookie RequestHeader using a regex to prevent sending too many cookies to the server, because the server wil simply drop the request on too large headers. However, I don't want to drop all the cookies, because I still niet the 'authorization' cookie. That being said, not all request contain the 'authorization' cookie.

```
# example cookie A:
foo=bar;authorization=jwt;more=bla
```

```
#example cookie B:
foo=bar;more=bla
```

Using zalando's skipper filter, I can modify the request header like so:

```
zalando.org/skipper-filter: modRequestHeader("Cookie", "^(.*)(authorization=.[^;]+;)(.*)$", "$2")
```

This will work in case of A, but not in case of B, as then I'll get ALL the cookies instead of NONE.

So how do I modify the regex to fix it to work in both cases?

EDIT:
Thanks @Wiktor

I ended up with this working solution, as a single cookie didn't need a trailing semicolon:

```
zalando.org/skipper-filter: modRequestHeader("Cookie", "^(?:(.*)(authorization=[^;]+)(.*)|.+)$", "$2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach to erase a string with no match is by adding a `.+` alternative:

```js
^(?:(.*)(authorization=[^;]+;)(.*)|.+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zXP1WL/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `(authorization=[^;]+;)` - Group 2: `authorization=` string and hen one or more chars other than `;` and then a `;`
  - `(.*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
    -`|` - or
  - `.+` - any one or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `$` - end of string.

Another way is to match the `authorization` part inside an optional group making the first dot pattern lazy:

```
^(.*?)(?:(authorization=[^;]+;)(.*))?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zXP1WL/3). As the whole non-matching string will land in Group 1, replacing with `$2` will still yield an empty output.

*Details*:

- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:(authorization=[^;]+;)(.*))?` - an optional non-capturing group

  - `(authorization=[^;]+;)` - Group 2: `authorization=`, one or more non-semicolons and a `;` char
  - `(.*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible

If you do not need to access the Group 3 value, remove the parentheses from the last `.*`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your speedy and thorough reply! Very generous.
It did exactly what I wanted, although I needed to remove the last semicolon otherwise the cookie parser didn't work. So this was the line I ended up using (see adjusted question)